# Prevent SQL injection for array ( xxx IN (y1, y2, y3, ...) )

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm using raw SQL code in Ruby on Rails. For preventing SQL injections I use e.g.

`... WHERE name = :name`

However, now I have an array of strings, which are user-set filters for retrieving data from the database. I need to escape this as well, but am not sure how to approach it. The current (vulnerable) code is (where `filter[:values]` is the array of user-set filters)

`AND answer_value IN (#{filter[:values].join(',')}))`

I was thinking of creating a string_array like this, for the amount of present filters:

```
escaped_filters = [
  "filter_1",
  "filter_2",
  "filter_3"
]
```

have the code use that:

`AND answer_value IN (#{escaped_filters.join(',')}))`

and somehow get those strings replaced by the actual filters. I'm not getting further than this, but could use an honest opinion of what is the actual right approach for this. Even if this might work, is it actually escaping injections?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you first explain why you need raw SQL as both of these fit nicely into the high level Query Methods? Secondly ActiveRecord has a bunch of sanitizers you could leverage [`ActiveRecord::Sanitization::ClassMethods `](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really did need to create a SQL string the correct way is to create a number of placeholders equal to the number of elements in the array:

```
where(
  "answer_value IN (#{ Array.new(filter[:values].length, '?').join(',') })",
  *filter[:values]
)
```

This is safe from a SQL injection as the user input is not used to create the SQL string and the bound parameters are escaped by the db adapter.

However you most likely don't even need it since ActiveRecord will automatically turn arrays into `WHERE IN (?, ?, ?, ...)` when you use the high level query interface:

```
where(
  answer_value: filter[:values]
)
```

Comment: You could use named placeholders instead of positional by using a hash and its keys instead of `?` - however it doesn't really offer any advantages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, this seems to use the ActiveRecord functions, where I'm trying to use the `find_by_sql` with raw SQL inside.

Comment: The same answer still applies. Use placeholders and pass the  bound parameters to `find_by_sql`. https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/10/28/bind-parameters-in-activerecord-sql-queries.html